# Захватить лямбдой аргументы вариативного шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Нужно сделать враппер внутри шаблонного метода.

Подскажите, как правильно передать в лямбду список аргументов:

```
template <typename Func, typename... Args>
void exec(Func&& func, Args&&... args)
{
    auto worker = [this, f = std::forward<Func>(func), a = std::forward<Args>(args)...]()
    {
        try
        {
            f(a);
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e)
        {
            std::cerr << e.what();
        }

    };
    std::async(worker);
}
```

как синтаксически правильно сделать передачу в этой строке:

```
a = std::forward<Args>(args)...
```

не понимает компилятор.
хотя вызов (без враппера) метода exec вот таким образом работает:

```
someInstance.exec(std::forward<Func>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вот так [работает](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wwTRUoaypqPtaBju):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Func, typename... Args>
void exec(Func&& func, Args&&... args)
{
    auto worker = [f = std::forward<Func>(func), ...a = std::forward<Args>(args)]()
    {
        f(a...);
    };
    
    worker();
}

void f(int a, double b) {
    std::cout << a << " " << b << "\n";
}

int main() {
    exec(f, 42, 1.234);
}
```

Но нужно C++20.

Для [C++17](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cU2h5a7ICIVfb2by) можно обернуть в `std::tuple`:

```
template <typename Func, typename... Args>
void exec(Func&& func, Args&&... args)
{
    auto worker = [f = std::forward<Func>(func), a = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)]()
    {
        std::apply(f, a);
    };
    
    worker();
}
```

Comment: В C++17 к сожалению нет.
error: expected identifier before ‘...’ token
auto worker = [this, f = std::forward<Func>(func), ...a = std::forward<Args>(args)]()

Comment: @IvanSodorenko добавил вариант для С++17